# How to identify unused or least used Azure resources

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Over a period of time many resources have been created by our team mates .Which is causing an cost overheads.
To reduce the cost and optimize the resource management we want to identify these unused resoruces in Azure.
can you guide me on how to identify these resoruces.

Comment: Do you mean any resources or only azure-functions? (that is mapped in your tags)

Comment: Are there any resources in Azure DevOps, or just on Azure Portal?

Comment: @ShamraiAleksander: It is for any azure resource

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT: Its on Azure Portal

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the tool [**Azure Orphaned Resources**](https://github.com/dolevshor/azure-orphan-resources?tab=readme-ov-file#azure-orphaned-resources-v20) to monitor the unused resources under your Azure subscription.

Follow the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/dolevshor/azure-orphan-resources?tab=readme-ov-file#how-to-use-it) to configure the **Azure Workbooks** with this tool on Azure Portal.

Comment: Can we see name of the resource or we can sse only number of resources that are unused?

Comment: @MiniSu, Yes. You can get the information from the detailed pages. Just try it and you can find more details.

Answer (score -1):

There's no easy way to do this. One thing you can try is, turn them off and see what breaks.

Comment: Turning off the resources can be the last option and in production we cant do that.So think from production resource perspective as well

Comment: Fair point, but if you don't even know where your critical resources live you already have major problems.